# Entity, Boundary, and Control

Tags: uml, entity, controls, boundary

**Problem:** Consider the Person, Student, Teacher, Course, Enroll, and User_Interface classes. This is part of a university computer system where students take courses that are taught by teachers. The Enroll class is used to enroll a student in a class. Identify the entity, boundary, and control classes.

**My Answer:** The entities are the student teacher and course because they represent system data, The User-Interface Classes are the boundary classes because they interact with the user, and finally the person is the control, because the person can be a student/teacher and the student/teacher has a course.

**Question:** I'm a little confused on this, I'm not sure if my answer is right, and I am also confused on where the enroll class fits in. I think it's considered an interface, but only for students. If that is the case how would I write that in a class diagram? Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nope. Not the right place to get your homework done here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that Person is just as well a entity. You can make Person an interface instead of a class, this way you can force Teacher and Student to implement some behaviors and/or properties that they have in common (like name, address, etc.).

The position of your Enroll class in the diagram depends on the functionality you want your Enroll class to offer. If it's just a table in your database to couple Students and Courses you might not need a Enroll class at all.

The Control layer in your UML are 'managers' that actually bring logic to your application, you do this to keep the logic separate from your entities (like the Person class). More on why to keep those things seperate: [Single responsibility principle - Wikipedia](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Single_responsibility_principle).